# Vim function expand always return empty string

Tags: vim

These days I found when I opened vim under some folders, function `expand` doesn't work as expected, it always returns empty string, in a result, some of my vim plugins cannot work.

This can be reproduced with the following steps:

```
# cd some_folder
# vim
:echo expand('123')    # empty output here
```

This does not happen in all folders, but I cannot find the pattern of these folders.

I suspect there could be some plugins which overwrite the `expand` function, but I don't know how to troubleshoot it.

Can someone give any clues on how to debug this issue?

Comment: Functions such as `expand` cannot be overwritten by plugins. As stated in `:help :function`, user defined functions must start with capital letters. You could confirm that by entering `:function expand()`.

Comment: As you can reproduce the issue, you could try binary search: move away half of your plugins, then the other half, repeat on the set that was present when the problem happens. You could do the same for your `.vimrc`.

Comment: Are you actually using `expand('123')`?

Comment: @FDinoff, I am using `echo expand('123')`, under other folders, this command can output `123`.

Comment: @mMontu, thanks for your explanation, yes, `expand` cannot be overwritten. I will try your advice and find out which plugin/script cause this problem.

Comment: @HanHe you are welcome, I'm glad you figured it out yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the root cause, in my vimrc, I've set:

```
set wildignore+=*/tmp/*,*.so,*.swp,*.zip,*.pyc,*.o
```

Then when I was in the folder with `tmp` in the path, `expand` would always return empty string. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Interesting. It even mentions it in the first sentence of `:h expand()`